# Curious convolution

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

Today, I found the following algorithmic problem:

> Given a sequence of $N\le 1000$ of zeroes and ones, for exactly $K\le1000$ times we choose an element and flip it. Count the number of move sequences of flippings such that the final sequence is only zeores modulo a large prime number ($10^9+7$). Two sequences are considered different if for some $i\le K$, their $i$th movement is different.

After some thought, I realized that it was basically asking for the coefficient of $x^k$ in:
$$\left(\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}\right)^{c_0}\left(\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}\right)^{c_1}k!$$
Where $c_0$ and $c_1$ are the amount of zeroes and ones in the original sequence, respectively. I was able to solve the problem by chopping the summations to the relevant terms, modular inverses, exponentiation by squaring and naive convolution, resulting in a worst case complexity $O(n^2\log(n))$, which proved enough to get an accepted solution.

Using FFT convolution, we may chop the running time down to $O(n\log^2(n))$. But does some or both sums represent the series some(known) function? Is there an algorithm with a lower complexity? Is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: The sums in brackets are $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$; not sure if this helps much, though.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That's nice. Well, just for fun we may use the identity $\sinh(x)\cosh(x)=2\sinh(x)$. I don't know if there is some result about the power series of a known power series or hyperbolic functions specificly, but maybe somthing interesting shows up.